# Roles a Usuarios con Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Buenas tardes compañeros, estoy creando una Intranet con ASP.NET MVC 5.
Seleccione la opción de Autenticación de Windows para que mis usuarios utilicen la misma contraseña con la cual se logean en su sesión.

Mi pregunta es como puedo asignar roles a los usuarios para poder mostrar/ocultar menus dependiendo de su rol.

Gracias por su ayuda.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui se reponse a la pregunta

[Recipe: Implementing Role-Based Security with ASP.NET 2.0 using Windows Authentication and SQL Server](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASPNET-20-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server)

como veras es algo mixto, si bien te autenticas en windows, los roles los defines en una base de datos

En la configuracion usaras

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="SqlRoleManager"
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
           connectionStringName="SqlRoleManagerConnection"
           applicationName="MyApplication" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

indicando el connection string a la db de roles

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlRoleManagerConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BasePageSample;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
    </add>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Recuerda que tienes que crear la estructura de tablas de `asp.net membership`

[Configuring ASP.NET 2.0 Application Services to use SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/423703)

para tener la tabla de roles